# Оптимальное распараллеливание задачи по нахождению порождающего полинома CRC32

Tags: c#

Исключительно в образовательных целях разбираю задачу по нахождению порождающего полинома для CRC32.
Знаем массив данных, знаем CRC32 по этому массиву, нужно найти порождающий полином.

```
        uint crc_Target = 0x62e2c0d8;

        byte[] data =
        {
            ///
        };

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        uint maxValue = 0xf4240;

        for (uint i = 0; i <= maxValue; i++)
        {
            if (crc32(data, i) == crc_Target)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Done:{i:X}");
            }
        }            

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

получаем, что время выполнения в одном потоке ~8500 мс на 1000000 вариантов на ноуте с 4 физическими ядрами.

если заменить этот код на этот:

```
     var result = Parallel.For(0, maxValue, i =>
        {
            if (crc32_2(data, (uint)i) == crc_Target)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Done:{i:X}");
            }
        });
```

То получим ~1200 мс. Что примерно совпадает с моими теоретическими расчётами типа 8 логических ядер, параллельно должно быть примерно в 8 раз быстрее. Так и выходит 8500 мс и 1200 мс примерно...

Процы при этом нагружаются на 100% если поставить количество итерация побольше. Всё хорошо и на ноуте меня всё устраивает.
Переношу приложение на Windows Server 2012R2 c 2 процами по 20 ядер. Запускаюсь и получаю на 1 млн итераций 800 мс. но даже если поставить maxValue = 0xffffffff, то процы на сервере полностью не загружаются как на ноуте. Загрузка по процам идёт какая-то рваная, то и дело просадки до 0 по отдельным ядрам.
Почему на сервере приложение ведёт себя по другому? Это сама серверная винда там что-то скидывает, либо можно как-то оптимизировать приложение, чтобы дать равномерную нагрузку на все ядра и увеличить скорость расчётов?

Comment: [How to: Speed Up Small Loop Bodies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-speed-up-small-loop-bodies) - попробуйте такой подход

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"Done:{i:X}");` может операция ввода-вывода ограничивает ваши параллельные потоки?

Comment: Возможно, зависит он настроек ThreadPool. И от загрузки пула потоков.

Comment: @tym32167 вывод сработает только 1 раз, когда полином будет найден

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov специально ThreadPool не тюнил, всё по умолчанию.

Comment: Parallel.For по умолчанию использует потоки из пула. Возможно, на сервере часть из этих потоков простаивает (отсюда загрузка не 100%) в ожидании завершения IO-операций.

Comment: [`ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism?view=netframework-4.8) - `Parallel.For(0, maxValue, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 }, i => { .. })` ([ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9538452/12888024))

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov по первому предложению там максимум int...при использовании maxValue = 0xffffff0 приложение отъедает более 5 Гигов памяти. Проц грузит ровно, получается красиво. По тестам скорость ниже, но не на много. 4531 мс по 1-му методу и 5 гиг памяти на накладные раcходы. по моему методу 3778 мс и 9 мб памяти. это на 10 млн итераций.

Comment: Скорость ниже? Странно. Не верю!(с) Покажите, как сделали.

Comment: Кстати, если вывод всего один, то цикл нужно прерывать (break), когда результат найден.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решение для использования всех ядер для конкретно моего случая сработало изменение целевой платформы на x64. Это касается и с++.

Рабочий код на C#:

```
        var result = Parallel.For(0, maxValue, (i, state) =>
        {
            if (crc32_2(data, (uint)i) == crc_Target)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Done:{i:X}");
                state.Break();

            }
        });
```

время нахождение порождающего полинома 511322 мс.

Рабочий код на С++:

```
run_with_cancellation_token([minValue, maxValue, data, size, target_CRC, &cts]()
{
    parallel_for(minValue, maxValue, [data, size, target_CRC, &cts](uint value)
    {
        if (crc32(data, size, value) == target_CRC)
        {
            std::cout << "CRC find: " << hex << value << endl;
            cts.cancel();
        }
        
    });

}, cts.get_token());
```

время нахождение порождающего полинома 141919 мс.
Код на с++ оказался почти в 5 раз быстрее.

Comment: Используйте `state.Stop()` вместо `state.Break()`.